# Either i get Invalid syntax or expected string or Unicode, float found

Tags: python, string, opencv, syntax

At first, I was getting an expected str or unicode object, float found when trying to put my velocity result into `cv2.putText` function. after a bit of kerfuffle, I managed to convert my velocity reading into a string.

Now as soon as I put the velocity in `cv2.putText`, the following line of code would have a `syntaxError: invalid Syntax`, and if I removed that the next one and so forth. as soon as the cv2.putText function is removed, it works again.

```
if Ydistance >5:
     velocity = (Ydistance / time) 
     velocity = string(velocity)
     #print(type(velocity))
     cv2.putText(frame, "".format(velocity), (10,500), font, 4,
         (255,255,255), cv2.LINE_AA)

     elif Ydistance ==0.0:
         continue
```

`string(velocity)` is a class which converts it to a string, when using `velocity = str(velocity)` or `velocity = unicode(velocity)` , velocity remained a float

thanks in advance

Comment: The `cv2.putText...` line is dedented, exiting the `if/elif/else` block. Move it under the `if`.

Comment: Sorry that was me being careless and not double checking before posting the question, in the code it is aligned correctly

Comment: Do you still have the problem? Can you post the stack trace? In the updated question, there is a space before the `elif` causing another indent problem and a colon after `continue` causing a syntax error.

Comment: That's me failing to check it again sorry. I removed the colon and that made no difference. currently, the putText is out the loop and causes an invalid syntax for the code below. 
as for the StackTrace, I tried doing it earlier (new at python), after multiple failed attempts I gave on that mission

Comment: I'm not trying to drive you crazy, but.... now the `elif` is indented too far.

Comment: Is the error about the `continue` statement not being in a loop? Once I clean up the code fragment, that is the one problem that remains. It could be just that you are showing us a smaller snippet of your code. But that's also why its good to post a working example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: so the coding is on my RPI and I'm writing this up on a desktop.. on the actual code, the 'elif' is in line with my if statement.  I'm coming up to 12 hours in uni library and my brain is frazzled

Comment: No @tdelaney , I'm trying to put the velocity values on my frame by using the cv2.putText function. as soon as this function is used in the code I get a Syntax error afterwards. So where it is currently placed causes the elif to be an error, if I move the putText out the loop it causes the cv2.imshow("frame", frame) to have a syntax error. 

but If I remove the putText the code works fine without any errors

Answer (score 0):

If I clean up spacing (the indent of the `elif` and using 4 spaces consistently - you seem to have 5) and put the code in a loop, I do not get a syntax error. The code doesn't run of course, but the syntax is fine. Now I have a running demonstration of a syntactically correct program that everyone can test.

```
while True:
    if Ydistance >5:
        velocity = (Ydistance / time) 
        velocity = string(velocity)
        #print(type(velocity))
        cv2.putText(frame, "".format(velocity), (10,500), font, 4,
            (255,255,255), cv2.LINE_AA)

    elif Ydistance ==0.0:
        continue
```

Running it I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "o.py", line 2, in <module>
    if Ydistance >5:
NameError: name 'Ydistance' is not defined
```

which is great because I no longer have syntax issues.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on mine, but my Ydistance is defined right about that code as: 
'Ydistance = ((dY  / px_mm))'